# Couldn't Load OWL file using OWLAPI

Tags: owl-api

I’m trying to load .owl file using owlapi thorough net beans to insert individual and its data properties using the code listed in owlapi documentation but it couldn't load the file, but when I converted the .owl file to .rdf format it was loaded successfully and i was able to insert the required data. I need to manipulate .owl file not .rdf format

Following is the code I have used to load the .owl without succeed

> ```
>      File fileBase = new File("src/java/ontology.owl);
>      OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
>      OWLOntology ontology= manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(fileBase);
> ```

but when i have used the rdf fromat as shown below it was loaded succefully

> ```
>      File fileBase = new File("src/java/ontology.rdf);
> ```

So how can I overcome this issue and load the .owl file?

Is the following command is the best command to save the axioms to ontology file?

> manager.saveOntology(ontology);

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you checking your OWL file. If it can't parse the ontology it will throw an exception. You need to catch and read the exception. Most probably is a parsing problem. Your commands are totally fine.

Saving the ontology by your command is fine, but the best way according to OWL documentation is to "apply changes" after each change. Something like:

```
manager.applyChange(axiom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with the .owl file of yours. Use the link below to validate your ontology file
http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/validator/